# Test XMLHttpRequest load callback in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmldom

I have some code that runs in the browser as a response to an AJAX request:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  var xmlResponse = e.target.responseXML;

  // a bunch of code that uses .querySelector and .querySelectorAll
  // on xmlResponse to find nodes and then it
  // calls .querySelector/.querySelectorAll on those nodes to find 
  // other nodes, or .textContent to read their content.
});
req.open('GET', url);
req.send();
```

I have extracted the code that does the parsing to a separate function and I would like to test it in Node, because it's easier to lint, test and bundle automatically.

The problem I have, however, is that in Node I did not find a way to parse an XML file into an object that supports `.querySelector()`, `.querySelectorAll()` and `.textContent()`, and I need to create such an object and pass it to my function to be tested.

Is there a way to do that? I tried some npm packages, but found none that provided this functionality.

Comment: use a headless browser like phantom

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your suggestion! I was hoping for a more lightweight alternative, but if I don't find any, phantom would probably do it.

Comment: could also try jsdom

Comment: @charlietfl I tried it, but `querySelector*` methods are not supported.

Comment: Maybe rewrite your function to work without `querySelector*`? Those are not XML-specific functions, but additions to the HTML DOM. The much more appropriate tool to pick specific XML nodes would be XPath (as a [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath) and [in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate))

Comment: @Tomalak That makes sense. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.